# Uploaded files to automatically be 755

Tags: 16.04, directory, users, ftp, user-management

I have setup ftp and a user but every time a user uploads content to that directory that content is set to 600, and since this is for a website it means nobody can see it.

I need it so when they upload it has the permissions automatically set to 755.

I did do this

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www
```

but this only seems to work when I'm uploading (the root user) 
but when they do it changes whatever they upload to 600

Comment: I think the real question here should be "why are the permissions set to 600 in the first place, and what is setting it like that?"

Comment: @JourneymanGeek it is tagged ftp ;) so I would say: check the config settings of the ftp program used.

Comment: or the umask setting on the destination system

Comment: AFAIK it should be a `umask` setting in the configuration of whatever ftp *server* you are using. IMHO *file* permissions should be set to at most 644. For example, `vsfptd` has  `local_umask` and `anon_umask` parameters.

Comment: im using VSFTPD

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/201305/default-owner-permissions-of-created-files-via-vsftpd